# Fancybox direct url redirection

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a homepage which opens in modal window a series of iframes and external files.

My structure is similar to this

```
<a href="page1.html" class="fancybox inframe">Page 1</a>
<a href="page2.html" class="fancybox inframe">Page 2</a>
<a href="page3.html#2" class="fancybox inframe">EXAMPLE PAGE</a>
<a href="page3.html#6" class="fancybox inframe">Page 4</a>
```

Note that also, some links might point directly to a specified panel.

Fancybox generates an url in this form http://domain.com/page3.html#2
If I access that page directly by typing it in the browser, I would like to redirect to my homepage.html and open the corresponding fancybox.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible that the same URL returns different responses from the server: one is a content of fancybox and the other one is the whole window with opened fancybox.

You have to add at least a querystring parameter to distinguish them.
For example if user does not add any querystring parameters and just type in URL, you can implement logic to open fancybox at document ready event.

On the other hand when you show the window programmatically you may provide a parameter and just show the content.

Comment: In fact we are using parameters! I just want to have a redirect from domain.com/page3.html#2 to domain.com/index.html with #2 panel from page3.html open in fancybox. Hope I've been clear.